# How to properly generate the data structure for these nested HTML lists

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, css-selectors

Say I have HTML like this:

```
<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <p>
          <b>Title A</b>
        <p>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Item 1:</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <p><b>Content title 1.1</b></p>
                <p>Content 1.1</p>
                <p>Content 1.1b</p>
                <p>Content 1.1c</p>
                <p>Content 1.1d (arbitrary paragraph number follows content title)</p>
                <p>Content ...</p>
                <p><b>Content title 1.2</b></p>
                <p>Content 1.2</p>
                <p>Content 1.2b</p>
                <p>Content 1.2...</p>
                ...
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Item 2:</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <p><b>Content title 2.1</b></p>
                <p>Content 2.1</p>
                <p><b>Content title 2.2</b></p>
                <p>Content 2.2</p>
                ...
              </td>
            </tr>
            ...
          </tbody>
        </table>

        <p>
          <b>Title B</b>
        <p>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Item 1b:</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <p><b>Content title 1b.1</b></p>
                <p>Content 1b.1</p>
                <p><b>Content title 1b.2</b></p>
                <p>Content 1b.2</p>
                ...
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Item 2b:</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <p><b>Content title 2b.1</b></p>
                <p>Content 2b.1</p>
                <p><b>Content title 2b.2</b></p>
                <p>Content 2b.2</p>
                ...
              </td>
            </tr>
            ...
          </tbody>
        </table>

        ...
```

It's not a very semantic structure, and there isn't nesting like you would like for the final data structure (below). However, enough information is present in the HTML to recover the nested data structure.

The obvious, first approach to converting this into the data structure is to just start at the top/first node, and work your way down. But this requires a lot of manual code, you have to manually figure out all the details of how to reconstruct the nesting and such, which ends up taking quite some time.

So instead I am wondering how to do it like this: gather up each *level* of data into sets. Then just wire up the sets as appropriate.

So that would look *something* like this:

```
var titles = document.querySelector(
  'body > div > div > div > p > b'
)
var items = document.querySelector(
  'body > div > div > div > table tr:nth-child(odd) td'
)
var itemContentTitles = document.querySelector(
  'body > div > div > div > table tr:nth-child(even) p b'
)
// somehow select all children after the content title, 
// up until the next content title or til 
// there are no more elements.
var itemContents = document.querySelector(
  'body > div > div > div > table tr:nth-child(even) p'
)
```

Once you have the data in these arrays essentially, the main problem is how to *weave them together* properly. The end result you want to be like this:

```
[
  {
    text: 'Title A',
    items: [
      {
        text: 'Item 1',
        items: [
          {
            text: 'Content title 1.1',
            items: [
              { text: 'Content 1.1' },
              { text: 'Content 1.1b' },
              { text: 'Content 1.1c' },
              { text: 'Content 1.1d' }
              ...
            ]
          },
          {
            text: 'Content title 1.2',
            items: [
              { text: 'Content 1.2' },
              { text: 'Content 1.2b' },
              { text: 'Content 1.2...' }
              ...
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text: 'Item 2',
        items: [
          {
            text: 'Content title 2.1',
            items: [
              { text: 'Content 2.1' }
              ...
            ]
          },
          {
            text: 'Content title 2.2',
            items: [
              { text: 'Content 2.2' }
              ...
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    text: 'Title B',
    items: [
      ...
    ]
  }
]
```

The question is, how you can go from the arrays of items that were selected with some basic CSS selectors (and so doesn't require tons of custom programming), to this nested JSON data structure.

It seems as though you should be able to iterate through each item in each list, and then check it's relation to a parent. Of course, we would specify which list should be applied as children to some other list. So we might do:

```
function assignChildren(parents, children) {

}
```

Then do:

```
assignChildren(titles, items)
```

But we probably actually have to start from the bottom up, and do:

```
assignChildren(itemContentTitles, itemContents)
```

The tricky thing here is how to then solve the problem of knowing which `itemContents` item belongs to which `itemContentTitle`. We know from the HTML how they are related. It is basically this:

```
itemContent
  .parentNode
  .parentNode
  .previousElementSibling
    .firstElementChild
      .firstElementChild
```

But the question is, how we can solve this problem *generically*, so that custom code doesn't need to be written. That is, you just do this:

```
assignChildren(itemContentTitles, itemContents)
```

...And get the nested JSON structure. It seems it would work something like this:

Start at the `itemContents` element (one of the child list items). Then we know the parent selector that found the parent items. So navigate upward and backward and downward somehow, to match up with the parent selector for that item. This is where it starts to get tricky and I'm having trouble seeing how to do it without basically scanning the entire DOM and checking the full generated selector path for each item (sorta thing). Wondering how to accomplish this. Doesn't have to be super performant, but good performance is always a plus.

The reason for doing it this way is because then it would only require you to specify the selectors to the different parts of the nested JSON structure, and how each selector is related to it's parent. You wouldn't have to write custom code for every single selector as you navigate the DOM.

The main question is how to do the weaving of the children to the parents in the above scenario.